# Nhibernate Mapping interface

Tags: interface, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

How to map an interface using fluent Nhibernate

```
class Product {

public virtual IProductStructure ProductStructure { get; set; }

}


 public class ProductMap : SubclassMap<Product>
    {
        public ProductMap()
        {
            HasOne(x => x.IProductStructure).PropertyRef(x => x.Product).Cascade.All();
        }
    }

public interface IProductStructure
    {
        Product Product { get; set; }
    }
```

error : NHibernate.MappingException : property-ref to unmapped class: .....Test.IStructure
thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping needs to be to a concrete class. In your case to the implementation of `IProductStructure`.

Comment: Do you have a class that implements IProductStructure? Eg. `public class MyProductStructure : IProductStructure`. In this case, in your map class you would map to MyProductStructure.

Comment: You are still going to have to map to concrete classes but you are going to have to discriminate on something. See if this helps: [inheritance mapping](http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-8-inheritance-mapping)